# Regex get code and description in a not well-formed txt

Tags: regex

As a PDF conversion of a table yelds:

```
8703.60.00   - Outros veículos, equipados para propulsão, simultaneamente, com um
               motor de pistão alternativo de ignição por centelha (faísca*) e um
               motor elétrico, suscetíveis de serem carregados por conexão a uma
               fonte externa de energia elétrica                                       25
             Ex 01 - De cilindrada não superior a 1.000 cm3                             7
             Ex 02 - De cilindrada superior a 1.000 cm3, mas não superior a 2.000
               cm3                                                                     13
8703.70.00   - Outros veículos, equipados para propulsão, simultaneamente, com um
               motor de pistão de ignição por compressão (diesel ou semidiesel) e
               um motor elétrico, suscetíveis de serem carregados por conexão a
               uma fonte externa de energia elétrica                                   25
8703.80.00   - Outros veículos, equipados unicamente com motor elétrico para
               propulsão                                                               25
8703.90.00   - Outros
```

I'm trying with this pattern:

```
/(\d{2,4}\.\d{1,2}|\d{2,4}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2})\s{2,}(.*)/s
```

But I can't find a way to stop group evaluation (the last `(.*)` of regex pattern) and get all codes and descriptions.

In another way, if I remove `/s` from pattern, I got all codes, but descriptions came incomplete (Only return descriptions before first `\n`).

How can I get all codes and descriptions after new lines?

**Follow my tests:**
https://regex101.com/r/PdtQCf/1

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: I'm using pcre (php)

Comment: Remove the "single line" flag and you'll be a lot closer.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying without `/s`, but I can't get descriptions after new lines

Comment: Try something like this : https://regex101.com/r/PdtQCf/2

Comment: It's a great improvement thanks! But in `87.03`, and another items description come truncated

Comment: why you delete the question for the sum?

Comment: undeleted... I was thinking it`s a better place in dba.stackoverlow, but btw... I think it`s a very specific issue for programmers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
(\d{2,4}\.\d{1,2}|\d{2,4}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2})\s{2,}(.*(?:\n(?!)\s{4,}.*)*)
```

It's your original regex, with the addition of checking for a linefeed followed by at least 4 (an arbitrary number to avoid page headers) space characters (except FF (i guess it is)) and then anything up to a linefeed. This last part can be repeated any number of times.

[Here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/PdtQCf/4).

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = <<<EOD
8703.60.00   - Outros veículos, equipados para propulsão, simultaneamente, com um
               motor de pistão alternativo de ignição por centelha (faísca*) e um
               motor elétrico, suscetíveis de serem carregados por conexão a uma
               fonte externa de energia elétrica                                       25
             Ex 01 - De cilindrada não superior a 1.000 cm3                             7
             Ex 02 - De cilindrada superior a 1.000 cm3, mas não superior a 2.000
               cm3                                                                     13
8703.70.00   - Outros veículos, equipados para propulsão, simultaneamente, com um
               motor de pistão de ignição por compressão (diesel ou semidiesel) e
               um motor elétrico, suscetíveis de serem carregados por conexão a
               uma fonte externa de energia elétrica                                   25
8703.80.00   - Outros veículos, equipados unicamente com motor elétrico para
               propulsão                                                               25
8703.90.00   - Outros          

EOD;

preg_match_all('/(\d{2,4}\.\d{1,2}|\d{2,4}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2})\s{2,}((?:.*?\R(?:\h+|$))*)/', $string, $match);
print_r($match);
```

**Explanation:**

```
/                               : regex delimiter
  (                             : start group #1
    \d{2,4}\.\d{1,2}            
    |
    \d{2,4}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}
  )                             : end group #1
  \s{2,}                        : 2 or more spaces
  (                             : start group #2
    (?:                         : start non capture group
      .*?                       : 0 or more any character but newline
      \R                        : any kind of linebreak
      (?:                       : start non capture group
        \h+                     : 1 or more horizontal spaces
        |                       : OR
        $                       : end of string
      )                         : end group
    )*                          : end group, 0 or more occurrences
  )                             : end group #2
/                               : regex delimiter. NO 's' modifier
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8703.60.00   - Outros veículos, equipados para propulsão, simultaneamente, com um
               motor de pistão alternativo de ignição por centelha (faísca*) e um
               motor elétrico, suscetíveis de serem carregados por conexão a uma
               fonte externa de energia elétrica                                       25
             Ex 01 - De cilindrada não superior a 1.000 cm3                             7
             Ex 02 - De cilindrada superior a 1.000 cm3, mas não superior a 2.000

            [1] => 8703.70.00   - Outros veículos, equipados para propulsão, simultaneamente, com um
               motor de pistão de ignição por compressão (diesel ou semidiesel) e
               um motor elétrico, suscetíveis de serem carregados por conexão a

            [2] => 8703.80.00   - Outros veículos, equipados unicamente com motor elétrico para

            [3] => 8703.90.00   - Outros          

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8703.60.00
            [1] => 8703.70.00
            [2] => 8703.80.00
            [3] => 8703.90.00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => - Outros veículos, equipados para propulsão, simultaneamente, com um
               motor de pistão alternativo de ignição por centelha (faísca*) e um
               motor elétrico, suscetíveis de serem carregados por conexão a uma
               fonte externa de energia elétrica                                       25
             Ex 01 - De cilindrada não superior a 1.000 cm3                             7
             Ex 02 - De cilindrada superior a 1.000 cm3, mas não superior a 2.000

            [1] => - Outros veículos, equipados para propulsão, simultaneamente, com um
               motor de pistão de ignição por compressão (diesel ou semidiesel) e
               um motor elétrico, suscetíveis de serem carregados por conexão a

            [2] => - Outros veículos, equipados unicamente com motor elétrico para

            [3] => - Outros          

        )

)
```

Comment: Your answer it's right too! I really appreciate your explanation - I'm studying it carefully